# Leaflet Error: Invalid LatLng object: (, NaN)

Tags: angular, typescript, leaflet

I am trying to create a circle with leaflet and I am getting this error:

> Error: Invalid LatLng object: (50.5, NaN)

I am using this code in Angular 2 to create my circle:

```
L.circle([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 200}).addTo(map);
```

---

I don't know why but this code below is OK:

```
L.circleMarker([50.5, 30.5], {radius: 200}).addTo(map);
```

But I want to use `L.circle()` function and not `L.circleMarker()`.

Comment: Do you use the recent versions of `leaflet` and `@types/leaflet`? Your first example looks fine.

Comment: @pzaenger Thank you ! I updated `leaflet` in my `package.json` from 0.7.7 to 1.0.3. Now it's working.

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

I simply updated `leaflet` from 0.7.7 to the most recent (1.0.3) in my `package.json` and I ran `npm install`.

Answer (score 4):

Btw, this is happened because you probably used the documentation of v1.x.x. It is used as below for 0.7.7;

```
L.circle([50.5, 30.5], 200).addTo(map);
```

http://leafletjs.com/reference-0.7.7.html#circle

Error message is a little bit misleading; 
https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/4235